# Idea highlighting tags in build.xml as not allowed

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, build.xml

My IDE (Idea) says: Element 'property' not allowed here.

And some other elements not allowed too. 
But project building successfully.
How can i fix this?

[image: Pic1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like IDEA is not recognizing the file as an Ant build file. The fact that the `<project>` tag is in red indicates that is, pardon the pun, the root of the problem. Try the following:

1. Got to *File > Invalidate Caches / Restart* (or *Application > Invalidate Caches / Restart* on Mac)
2. Click the `Invalidate and Restart` button on the "Invalidate Caches" dialog
3. Let IDEA restart and then re-index the project.

Another thing to check, although a long shot, is that the `Ant Support` plugin is enabled in *File > Settings > Plugins*.

If that does not solve the issue, can you please put your cursor on the `<project>` element and indicate what the error is for that element.

Comment: Eight years later, but I had a very similar issue which was only fixed by updating the IDEA to the latest.  I think it was related to JDK21 not yet being supported, but it surfaced in a very similar fashion as the OPs.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that xml prefix needed to be added to Ant files for IntelliJ to being to recogize them as such. Add this as the first line and most of the red is gone:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```